# How to search multiple words in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to search multiple words in Visual studio code. for instance, I want to list out all files with "application" and "service" in anywhere in the file. I tried regex "application.*service", but this only list file if both words are in same line. Any way to do this in vscode?